# nested ng-repeat $parent.$index and $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a strange bug that, unfortunately, I cannot replicate with jsfiddle.  I've commented out my entire code (Except libraries,etc) except for the following snippets.  Is there something obvious that I don't understand?  Any ideas?

This works and prints: (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1)

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
        <div>
            ({{$parent.$index}} {{$index}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this piece of code prints: (0,0) (1,1) (0,0) (1,1)

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{$parent.$index}} {{$index}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller is:

```
$scope.list  = [1, 2];
$scope.list2 = [1, 2];
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X5Tdh/2/)**

That's because the directive `ng-if` creates a new scope for itself, when you refer to `$parent`, it access the immediate `$parent`'s scope, i.e., the inner repeat expression's scope.

So if you want to achieve something you wanted like in the former, you may use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{$parent.$parent.$index}} {{$parent.$index}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you have more than one inner directives, you can use `ng-init` for storing `$index` in a variable for references in child scopes.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list" ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2" ng-init="innerIndex=$index">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{outerIndex}} {{innerIndex}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I strongly suggest you to go through this article on [understanding scopes in angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: You was ahead in few secs before I almost sent same answer. :)
Absolutely right solution.

Comment: $parent was not encouraged by Angular team. The answer below without using $parent is cleaner. Please follow that one guys. :P

Comment: Amazing @Raghav... this is a very concept in Angular which many newbie might not be knowing. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: what about splicing data from list or list2 on close button
I think ng-init will not be re-initialized

Answer (score 20):

Instead of using `ng-init` you can use the `(key, value)` `ng-repeat` syntax to get the parent index.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/12XkCLo1ZVciEQXN5XGY?p=preview)**

```
<div ng-repeat="(iKey, i) in list">
    <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
        <div ng-if="1">
            ({{iKey}} {{$index}})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is cleaner than using `ng-init`

Answer (score 2):

check out the [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/xLlygq4xNYIJuEPmjjct?p=preview)

ng-if is creating a new child scope because of which there is a need to add $parent.
i have created `myname` property which tells the scope name, using which you can check whats exactly happening..

```
<div ng-if="1">
    ({{$parent.$parent.$index}} {{$parent.$index}})
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-if` introduce an another scope, so one `$parent.` isn't enough.

You could double it like this `$parent.$parent.$index`, or remember the index of the outer `ng-repeat` in a different variable via `ng-init` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list" ng-init="listIndex = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="j in list2">
    <div ng-if="1">
      ({{listIndex}} {{$index}})
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/dtaBAmkU32BCsLASLs0C?p=preview