# How to set data in ng-repeat dynamicall using nested ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using nested *ng-repeat* in following code. The first *ng-repeat* is showing the IP List. In the second one I want to set data like "node0", "node1", "node2" etc. instead of node. These values should be set according to the *$index* variable in first *ng-repeat*.

```
  <div ng-repeat="ip in ipList track by $index">
        <div>
            <div class="box">
                <form action="">
                    <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="n in node">
                                    <td><input type="radio" name="column" /></td>
                                    <td>{{n}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
```

Comment: you are not very clear about how your arrays are set up. But you can try `ng-repeat="n in node[$index]"` if node is a collection of nodes

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want. can you please elaborate more on it??

Comment: you questions are not clear .

Comment: can you tell shape of object ? is node and iplist are different?

Comment: not clear, please paste the code snippet  from your controller here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nested ng-repeat $parent.$index and $index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094201/nested-ng-repeat-parent-index-and-index)

Comment: show us your iplist and other objects you want to show