# AngularJS Drag and Drop failing on ng-repeat with dynamic index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with Drag and Drop with Angular JS on my Quiz

The code works fine if I  just use one object  simulated here by the index number i.e. as shown below   myQuest[0].answers

```
    ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuest | limitTo: 5">
      <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}} ?</p>

      <li   class=""
            lr-drag-src="reorder" lr-drop-target="reorder"
            ng-repeat="Answer in myQuest[0].answers ">
          <img ng-src="{{ Answer.image }}">
        {{Answer.id}}
      </li>
          <p class="txt">{{analysis}}</p>
          <div class="feedback">
```

but fails when I use the  code below which is required to move to next question  i.e   myQuest[$index].answers of the question to be answered
Symptoms:  The Drag and Drop reorder image reorders  by moving an answer to the next object /question  and not the question been answered

```
  ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuest | limitTo: 5">
      <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}} ?</p>

      <li   class=""
            lr-drag-src="reorder" lr-drop-target="reorder"
            ng-repeat="Answer in myQuest[$index].answers ">
          <img ng-src="{{ Answer.image }}">
          {{Answer.id}}
      </li>
          <p class="txt">{{analysis}}</p>
          <div class="feedback">
```

I've tried `track by $index` on both  parent and child  ng-repeats  to no avail

Comment: I suppose `myQuest[&index].answers` has a typo and your actual code is `myQuest[$index].answers`, right? please take a look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094201/nested-ng-repeat-parent-index-and-index/25094542) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256600/passing-2-index-values-within-nested-ng-repeat).

Comment: Could you reproduce the bug in a JsFiddle so that we can try fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it thankyou lzagkaretos

```
       ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuest track by $index | limitTo: 5"
       ng-init="**questionIndex** = $index" >
      <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}} ?</p>

      <li class=""

          lr-drag-src="reorder" lr-drop-target="reorder"
          ng-repeat="Answer in myQuest****[questionIndex]**.answers"
          ng-init="answerIndex = $index" >
```